# Neo4j not starting

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to run neo4j on my Mac machine and have installed JDK version 11.

```
loveleenbhargava@Loveleens-MacBook-Air neo4j-community-4.1.12 % javac -version        
javac 11.0.20
loveleenbhargava@Loveleens-MacBook-Air neo4j-community-4.1.12 % java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.20+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.20+0, mixed mode)
```

And neo4j - 4.1. 12 community version is downloaded from:

```
https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=4.1.12&flavour=unix&_gl=1*113yasn*_ga*MTY0NTg2ODA5NC4xNjg2OTIyOTcy*_ga_DL38Q8KGQC*MTY4NjkyMjk3NS4xLjEuMTY4NjkyNDY1Ny41My4wLjA.&_ga=2.57215594.1385011292.1686922972-1645868094.1686922972
```

When I go to 'neo4j-community-4.1.12' to run ./bin/neo4j start, it shows me this error in debug.log:

```
2023-07-28 04:40:44.860+0000 INFO [o.n.d.d.DefaultDatabaseManager] Creating 'system' database.
2023-07-28 04:40:45.106+0000 INFO [o.n.b.BoltServer] Bolt server loaded
2023-07-28 04:40:45.314+0000 INFO [o.n.d.d.DefaultDatabaseManager] Starting 'system' database.
2023-07-28 04:40:45.448+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] [system] Selected format 'RecordFormat:StandardV4_0[SF4.0.0]' for the new store /Users/loveleenbhargava/neo4j-community-4.1.12/data/databases/system
2023-07-28 04:40:45.831+0000 WARN [o.n.k.d.Database] [system] Exception occurred while starting the database. Trying to stop already started components. Could not get Throwable message field
java.lang.LinkageError: Could not get Throwable message field
I checked that there is nothing into the ./data/database/system directory.


loveleenbhargava@Loveleens-MacBook-Air neo4j-community-4.1.12 % ls -ltr !$
ls -ltr data/databases/system
total 0
```

Any leads to that?

Tried reinstalling the java versions but did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has gone away when I reinstalled everything from scratch. Funny, yes but the problem is not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an OpenJDK 11.0.20 bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2225018

Does neo4j work if you install the package `tzdata-java`?